# Error, return value 3221225477

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector <string> words; 

void splitSent (string sent);



int main ()
{
string sent;

cout << "Enter your sentence: " << endl;
getline (cin, sent);
splitSent (sent);     


string finalSent;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
 {  
    if (words[i] == "i")
    {
        finalSent += "I ";
        i++;
    }

    if (words[i] == "instructor")
    {
        finalSent += "name of prof ";
        i++;
    }

    finalSent += words[i];
    finalSent += " ";
 }

cout << "Final sentence is: " << finalSent << "." << endl;


return 0;
}


void splitSent (string sent)
{
int Pos = 0; // Position
string word;

while (Pos < sent.length())
{
    while ((Pos < sent.length()) && (sent[Pos] != ' '))
    {
        word += sent[Pos];
        Pos++;
        if (sent[Pos] == '.')
         {
            break;
         }
    };
words.push_back(word);
word = "";
Pos++;
}
}
```

This is my program so far, I'm trying to replace "i" with "I" and replace "instructor" with the name of my prof. However, every time there is more than two "i"s in a sentence, I keep getting an error message and I'm not sure why. I also get the same error message if there is the word "instructor" in my sentence

Comment: This code does not compile; you need to provide a minimal working example.  For example, we don't know what `splitSent` or `checkSent` do, and we don't know where `words` comes from.  Also, you need to explain what errors you're getting.

Comment: Yea, I just fixed it, could you take another look at it?

Comment: [child process exited with status 3221225477](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306272/apache-crashing-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-restarti) says this would be a segmentation fault - accessing memory which is not allocated. I'm willing to bet its because you increment `i` and then access it later on.

Comment: Use a debugger, trace your program execution, watch local variables especially loop variables.

Answer (score 1):

there's no need to manually increment the `i`. That's what the `for` loop does by the way. By incrementing `i` you are overshooting the vector's size and obviously accessing undefined memory

```
string finalSent;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    {
        if (words[i] == "i")
        {
            finalSent += "I ";
            continue;  
            //i++;
        }

        if (words[i] == "instructor")
        {
            finalSent += "name of prof ";
            continue;
            //i++;
        }

        finalSent += words[i];
        finalSent += " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Obicere mentioned in the comments, you're probably getting a segmentation fault because you're incrementing `i` manually, and then asking for `words[i]`.  You were probably only getting the segfault when "i" or "instructor" was at the end of the sentence, when the variable `i` was already as high as it should be.  But then you did `i++`, so `i` was one greater than it should be, and `words[i]` is asking for an element of `words` that is past its end.  This is how segfaults happen.

You should be more careful with your `if` statements and what happens after them.  Incidentally, using global variables is a bad idea.  In this case, you shouldn't define `words` at the top of your file, but you should pass it by reference.  Also, a good editor (emacs or vim) can keep your code tidier.

I'm not entirely sure what you wanted, so I may have messed up the flow control, but this code should be much closer to what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void splitSent (string sent, vector<string>& words);

int main () {
  string sent;
  vector<string> words;

  cout << "Enter your sentence: " << endl;
  getline(cin, sent);
  splitSent(sent, words);

  string finalSent;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i<words.size(); i++) {
    if (words[i] == "i") {
      finalSent += "I";
    } else if (words[i] == "instructor") {
      finalSent += "name of prof";
    } else {
      finalSent += words[i];
    }
    if (i<words.size()-1) { // Don't put a space before the period
      finalSent += " ";
    }
  }
  finalSent += ".";

  cout << "Final sentence is: " << finalSent << endl;

  return 0;
}

void splitSent (string sent, vector<string>& words) {
  int Pos = 0; // Position
  string word;

  while (Pos < sent.length()) {
    while ((Pos < sent.length()) && (sent[Pos] != ' ')) {
      word += sent[Pos];
      Pos++;
      if (sent[Pos] == '.') {
        break;
      }
    }
    words.push_back(word);
    word = "";
    Pos++;
  }
}
```