# PHP new SoapClient causing Apache crash

Tags: php, apache, soap

I am trying to setup a SoapClient in my PHP but it keeps crashing Apache

Here is my PHP:

```
try{
    $o_soap = @new \SoapClient(
        "local/path/to/my/wsdl.xml",
        array(
            'exceptions' => true
        )
    );
    var_dump($o_soap->__getFunctions());
}
catch(SoapFault $e){
    die($e->faultstring);
}
```

Here is the Apache Log:

```
[Wed Mar 15 11:26:57.422962 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00428: Parent: child process 8780 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed Mar 15 11:26:58.030023 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 15 11:26:58.030023 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Wed Mar 15 11:26:58.030023 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd.exe -d C:/WEB/Apache24_32bit'
[Wed Mar 15 11:26:58.035024 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9432
[Wed Mar 15 11:27:00.031223 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9432:tid 532] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Mar 15 11:27:02.336454 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00428: Parent: child process 9432 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed Mar 15 11:27:03.045678 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 15 11:27:03.045678 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Wed Mar 15 11:27:03.045678 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd.exe -d C:/WEB/Apache24_32bit'
[Wed Mar 15 11:27:03.061278 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 516] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9784
[Wed Mar 15 11:27:05.030913 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9784:tid 528] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

WSDL has been checked on https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com and returned no errors.

### Update

Looks like it comes from the WSDL... I tried another (smaller) one and got the expected result...

### Update 2

Solved using nusoap library

Comment: Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306272/apache-crashing-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-restarti#10306977

Comment: Using `@` to suppress errors is bad practice...